# Can I use firebase login (firebase auth) with android matrix sdk login

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Thanks in advance.
I am doing a customization with riot-android open source. I want to use firebase auth in my app with matix sdk.
I have done firebase login and I have firebase user.
How do you I connect my firebase user with riot (matrix-sdk)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not implemented yet.
The login is designed to work with the displayname/username/phone number + password.
This will require a server update.

https://github.com/vector-im/riot-android/issues/1705